# How can I explicitly tell the compiler what the return type is?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have an abstract class and an object of the same name in the same file.

How can I explicitly tell the compiler that the return type of `run` is the abstract class  CommandResult type not the object CommandResult type?

Base.scala

```
trait Base {
  def run[T]: Future[T]
}
```

X.scala

```
class X extends Base {
  override def run[CommandResult]: Future[CommandResult] = {
      // here return CommandResult, Success or Failure
  }
}

sealed abstract class CommandResult(val exitCode: Int)

object CommandResult {
  case object Success extends CommandResult(0)
  case object Failure extends CommandResult(1)
}
```

Comment: Why that generic? That doesn't make sense. Also, classes and objects have different types, you do not need to do anything to differentiate them.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Forgot to add some details. `X` extends 'Base` and implements the run method.

Comment: `run[T]` means it works for any type in the whole existence. Your subclass only works for only a couple of those infinite possibilities. That basically is a violation of the **Liskov** principle, meaning it is not possible to do. - Maybe you want to move that type parameter to the whole trait instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `def run[CommandResult]`, it means "run takes a type one parameter named CommandResult", that's why you are getting error like:

```
On line 3: error: type mismatch;
        found   : CommandResult.Success.type
        required: CommandResult              <--- The type parameter, 
                                              not the class or object.
```

The error indeed is very misleading. For example try `override def run[X]: Future[X]` and will see "required: X`.

If you do as [Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63479298/how-can-i-explicitly-tell-the-compiler-what-the-return-type-is#comment112251354_63479298) suggests:

```
trait Base[T] {
  def run: Future[T]
}

class X extends Base[CommandResult] {
  override def run: Future[CommandResult] = {
      Future(CommandResult.Success)
  }
}
```

It will work.